# Am I using the Repository pattern correctly in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, sequelize.js, repository-pattern

I use Sequelize to work with the database.
In my project, I encountered code duplication, and decided to study the repository design pattern, which will separate the work with the database and data output from the business logic. Having studied the information on the Internet, I decided to consolidate the material and check with more experienced programmers. I use the repository pattern correctly?
controller/user.controller.js

```
const userService = require('../services/user.service');

exports.userCreate = async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
   const user = await userService.userCreate(req.body);
   return res.status(201).json(user);
 } catch (e) {
   return next(e);
 }
}
```

services/user.service.js

```
const ApiError = require('../utils/error');
const userRepo = require('../repositories/user.repository');

exports.userCreate = async (data) => {
  if (!data) throw ApiError.badRequest('Bad');

  const { login } = data;

  if (!login) throw ApiError.badRequest('Bad');
   
  const password = 'hash';
  const user = await userRepo.userCreate({login, password});
  
  return user;
}
```

repositories/user.repository.js

```
const User = require('../models/User');

exports.userCreate = async (data) => {
  const { login, passowrd } = data;
  const user = await User.create({login, password});
  
  return {
    login: user.login,
  }
}
```

models/User.js

```
const { sequelize, Sequelize } = require('../config/db');

const User = sequelize.define('users', {
 id: {
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   autoIncrement: true,
   allowNull: false,
   primaryKey: true,
 },
 login: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
 },
 password: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
 }
});

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Yes, seems correct :) User repository should only handle User entity - which this is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your User model is fine, but the structure of the service seems a little weird. if all three of the functions userCreates are in separate files I'd recommend you combine them and rename services to Controllers, as services are usually used on the client side of things.

**services/user.service.js**

```
const User = require('../models/User')
// const userRepo = require('../repositories/user.repository') Not sure what this does
const ApiError = require('../utils/error')

module.exports = {
    async createUser (req, res) {
        try {
            if (!req.body) throw ApiError.badRequest('Bad')
            const { login } = req.body
            if (!login) throw ApiError.badRequest('Bad')

            const password = 'hash'
            const user = await User.create({ login, password })

            res.stauts(201).json(user.login)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.staus(500).send({
                error: err
            })
            // return next(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the service is directly dependent on the model which is the implementation detail. Now consider a situation that you need to change the ORM from sequelize to typeorm or prisma , but here the implementation is dependent on a specific ORM (sequelize), you will have to change all the instances where ORM dependent methods are called.

Comment: What repository pattern does is that it brings in an abstraction layer between your service and ORM / Database implementation , so you wont have to change the business logic methods (createUser) when the database implementation is changed (changing the ORM or moving to plain queries).